# Extract the gradient from the deriv command

Tags: r, gradient

A colleague asked me the following question the other day. In the following piece of code, how do you extract the gradient:

```
> x=5
> a = eval(deriv(~ x^3, "x"))
> a
[1] 125
attr(,"gradient")
      x
[1,] 75
```

My answer was

```
>  attr(a, "gradient")[1]
[1] 75
```

This syntax seems clunky to me. Is there a better way of extracting the gradient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure these count as *better*, but:

```
with(attributes(a), gradient)
```

or

```
attributes(a)$gradient
```

are alternatives that return the attributes as a list from which to select.

Answer (score 3):

Though it is no better than your method, you could make a function, `grad`, that takes a numeric with a gradient attribute and returns the gradient value.

```
grad = function(x)attr(x,"gradient")[1]

grad(a)
```

which is now reusable.